# OpenCV Python binding plays video very slow

Tags: python, performance, opencv, video

I'm processing and showing result of a video in python with opencv 2.4.4 (and 2.4.5), but frame speed is 1fps instead 30fps (I called `cv2.waitKey(1000 / 30)` ). I tried to play video without processing but result is the same. If I try to play the same video with c++ I can watch it with 30fps, but I want this result in python.

My computer is a Mac Os X 10.8.3 with python 2.7.2 and opencv 2.4.4, I tried also ubuntu with python 2.7.3 and opencv 2.4.5 but no changes in results.

I'm thinking of using a separate thread to play video or using scipy weave conversion to run only imshow code but I prefer a more clean and definitive solution.

**Edit:** the correct answer is the first comment by Eric. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any image processing between capture and display ?

Comment: Yes, but I tried to display only video without image processing and results are the same.

Comment: I don't understand the `1000/30` value. It is milliseconds, isn't it ? For 30 fps you need `cv2.waitKey(33)`.

Comment: You are right, I leaved 1000/30 instead of 33 for a distraction, but result of 1000/30 without float cast is 33 (It is 1 second in milliseconds over number of frame in 1 second). I tried both values but results don't change.

Comment: Could you pass here a pastebin with your python code ?

Comment: I noticed that in my tests I forgot to comment an important image processing! I deleted it and now works well! I'm so sorry I wasted your time, but your first hypothesis are right! Thank you!

Comment: Allright. Think to validate/upvote the answer/comment which helps you most in order to give clues for others with same problem. Then the question will be closed.